# Confused about how @id in structured data works

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

Basically, I'm trying to add `BlogPosting`, `TechArticle` and `WebPage` structured data types to my posts, but I'm getting errors in Google's structured data testing tool. They seem to be centred around when I link back to an `Organization` structured data type I've defined on my homepage, to save me having to repeat the same code across multiple pages.

Here's the structured data testing tool instance. Can anybody explain how I can properly link to the `Organization` data type (which is sitting on my homepage) in the `author`, `creator` and `publisher` properties?

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lukeharrison.dev%2Farticles%2Fmike-brewer-motors-wins-best-online-experience-at-autotraders-2018-retailer-awards%2F

I feel as though it may be down to me not fully understanding the `@id` property, and how to properly can use it to link structured data together to reduce repetitive data.

Here's the code involved:

- The `BlogPosting`
- The linked `Organisation`
- The errors I'm receiving

### Example of `BlogPosting`

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "BlogPosting",
    "about": "Great news! Mike Brewer Motors - a project I've been heavily involved in over the past few years - has won the 'Best Online Experience' at the Autotrader 2018 Retailer Awards.",
    "articleSection": "Blog Posts",
    "author": {
        "id": "https://www.lukeharrison.dev#organization"
    },
    "copyrightHolder": {
        "id": "https://www.lukeharrison.dev#person"
    },
    "copyrightYear": "2019",
    "creator": {
        "id": "https://www.lukeharrison.dev#organization"
    },
    "dateCreated": "2018-07-20",
    "dateModified": "2018-07-20",
    "datePublished": "2018-07-20",
    "description": "Great news! Mike Brewer Motors - a project I've been heavily involved in over the past few years - has won the 'Best Online Experience' at the Autotrader 2018 Retailer Awards.",
    "genre": "Web Design & Front-End Development",
    "headline": "Mike Brewer Motors wins 'Best Online Experience' at Autotrader's 2018 Retailer Awards - Luke Harrison",
    "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "height": 512,
        "url": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/c34b34964896ad0552a5b342ae08c1e2?s=512",
        "width": 512
    },
    "inLanguage": "en-GB",
    "isFamilyFriendly": "true",
    "keywords": [
        "news"
    ],
    "mainEntityOfPage": "https://www.lukeharrison.dev/articles/mike-brewer-motors-wins-best-online-experience-at-autotraders-2018-retailer-awards",
    "publisher": {
        "id": "https://www.lukeharrison.dev#organization"
    }
}
```

### Example linked `Organization`, which sits on another page

```json
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@id": "https://www.lukeharrison.dev#organization",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "additionalType": [
        "http://www.productontology.org/id/Web_design",
        "http://www.productontology.org/doc/Search_engine_optimization",
        "http://www.productontology.org/doc/Web_development"
    ],
    "foundingDate": "2013",
    "legalName": "Luke Harrison - UX / Web Developer",
    "logo": "https://www.lukeharrison.dev/img/share-26bfb69f23.png",
    "name": "Luke Harrison - UX / Web Developer",
    "sameAs": [
        "https://twitter.com/webdevluke?lang=en-gb",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/in/lukedidit/",
        "https://github.com/WebDevLuke",
        "https://codepen.io/lukedidit/"
    ],
    "url": "https://www.lukeharrison.dev"
}
```

### The errors I'm receiving in my `BlogPosting` structure

`author`, `creator` and `publisher`:

- > The attribute publisher.itemtype has an invalid value.
- > A value for the name field is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are about Google’s [Article rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article) (if you don’t want to get this rich result, you can ignore these errors).

For AMP pages, `author` and `publisher` are required properties. They require actual items as value, `@id` references are not supported. You can still provide the `@id`, but you need to specify the `@type` and the required properties in addition.